# how to set min and max rows on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend, textarea

I'm trying to set min and max rows to textarea and then edit in javaScript code. The problem is that I found it possible to only set rows attribute and don't know how to manipulate with this in javascript code

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```js
const myText = document.querySelector('.my-text');


myText.style.maxHeight = "400px";
myText.style.minHeight = "100px";
```

```css
.my-text {
      border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="my-text" rows="3"></textarea>
```